# Having trouble converting schema from Normalizr v2 to v3

Tags: javascript, redux, normalization, normalize, normalizr

I just updated to normalizr version 3.1.x so I can utilize the denormalization. Though they've significantly changed their API. I'm having trouble transferring my schemas over.

```
import { normalize, Schema, arrayOf, valuesOf } from 'normalizr';

const usersSchema =  new Schema('users')
const photosSchema =  new Schema('photos')
const phonesSchema =  new Schema('phones')

photosSchema.define({
  users: arrayOf(usersSchema)
})

phonesSchema.define({
  users: arrayOf(usersSchema)
})

usersSchema.define({
  photos: valuesOf(photosSchema),
  phones: valuesOf(phonesSchema)
})
```

That was my existing schema for users. I was also using the [redux-normalizr middleware](https://github.com/wbinnssmith/redux-normalizr-middleware) inside my redux action, so I connected the schema to my action like this:

```
import { usersSchema } from '../normalizrSchemas/usersSchemas.js'
import { arrayOf } from 'normalizr'

export function getUsers(data) {
  return  {
    type: 'GET_USERS',
    payload: data,
    meta: {
      schema : arrayOf(usersSchema)
    }
  }
}
```

This was my first attempt to convert the schema over. It doesn't seem you can call schema.Array the same way you could using `arrayOf`, so I thought I needed to move the array call into the schema.

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';

const photos = new schema.Entity('photos')
const phones = new schema.Entity('phones')
const user = new schema.Entity('user', {
    photos: [photos],
    phones: [phones]
})

const users= new schema.Array('users', user)

export { users }
```

the action is the same, but i've removed wrapping the schema in arrayOf. All of the users data is just getting dumped into results without any normalization. The data is a list of user object, and each object contains an id, which normalizr should pick up. I'm struggling to figure out how to get normalizr the identify that it's an array of object I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`schema.Array` does not accept a key string name ([docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#arraydefinition-schemaattribute)). The first argument should be the schema definition. So instead of

```
const users= new schema.Array('users', user)
```

You should use:

```
const users = new schema.Array(user)
```

Or, you could just use the shorthand for an array of a single entity type:

```
const users = [ user ];
```

Comment: hmm. it sems it didn't like the shorthand, spitting out `index.js:179 Uncaught Error: Normalize accepts an object for schema.`. Though it did accept the long form `new schema.Array(provider)`.  Yet all of the user object are still getting dumped into the results array, and entities is empty. I tired to simplify my code by removing photos and phones. Maybe I'll find some more info in the docs

Comment: Well it looks like it may just be that redux-normalizr just isn't compatible with version 3. When using `normalize` in my reducer with the schema is works fine. It's a shame i'll have to get rid of the middleware, but i'm excited to use normalizr v3! Thank you!